# another question of going to or will

Tags: will-vs-going-to

> I **am not going to** tell you how much I spent on this ring

> I **won't tell** you how much I spent on this ring

Which is the best sentence ?

I think in the first case the decision has made before speaking (it has already been planned before and it is an intention no to tell the price of the ring ) so going to should be better, but it could be also an instant decision so will could  also be good . May be will is stronger than going to and last "for ever"  whereas going to is limited in time

Comment: When you compare two things, you should ask **Which is the better sentence?** The answer is that neither is better. You can read into them whatever you wish but they mean exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are essentially identical. If you really want to split hairs, the "*will*" sentence is a decision made at the moment of speaking, whereas "*be going to*" sounds like a slightly firmer and stronger expression.

> I am not telling you how... ( this one would be most likely used if you mean to imply such expression )

As I said, it's hard to see any difference here and both are applicable for this context.

Comment: Exactly. And somebody else might split different hairs and come up with an opposite difference in ***their*** context.